# NodeJS Error Callback was already called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that this error exists here, and I try to read and that code but I always get this Error: Callback was already called.

My code is:

```
switch(data.type) {
   case 1:
     console.log('blablabla');
     break; 
   case 2:
     /* SSH - login */
     pool.query('SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) AS ip, pass, server FROM servers WHERE id=?',[data.id], function(err, rows, fields){
            /* SSH - connection */
            conn.connect({
                host: rows[0].ip,
                port: '22',
                username: 'root',
                password: decrypt(rows[0].pass, password)
            })

            /* SSH - ready */
            conn.on('error', function(err) {
                /* SSH - connection failed */
                return callback('Login To <b>'+rows[0].server+'</b> Failed!');
            })

            conn.on('end', function() {
                /* SSH - closed */
                console.log('ssh closed...')
            })

            conn.on('ready', function() {
                console.log('ready to execute terminal commands...')
            })
        })
        break;
    })
```

First time I call this function it works and I got

```
Login To Server Failed!
```

I call this function again and I got this error:

```
Error: Callback was already called.
```

After doing console.log I see that second time I call this function it is called twice so this is why this error about callback gets...so the problem is I try to put callback outside conn.on functions and inside but the second time that is called this function I get always this error..where in what place callbacks needs to be placed so that function does not get called twice?

UPDATE QUESTION:

I see when i add console.log to error and close event that each time i call this function i get one more event error and close called...see this:

First time called this function i get:

```
calling ssh...
error connecting to server...
ssh closed...
```

Second calling function:

```
calling ssh...
error connecting to server...
error connecting to server...
ssh closed...
ssh closed...
```

Third time calling function:

```
calling ssh...
error connecting to server...
error connecting to server...
error connecting to server...
ssh closed...
ssh closed...
ssh closed...
```

So is there a bug in SSH2 node js library or i im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events listenners are organised as an array; an regarding your code, the object << conn >> is external to the method you used. When you call it twice, you add a new listener to the array of the listenners of the object conn, making two listenners <<.on('error',... >> instead of one. See the picture below (https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

So you just need to initialize the object << conn >> before making a connection with it, to ensure that only one listener << on('error',... >> are affected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks...you are very smart...i im working in node about half year and never have this idea to think..i just added in this function to be locally new conn for ssh2 and now is working without error..i just added conn       = new client(); and all is now working perfect..on each new request new connection is created and all is working...thank you.

Comment: Just to ask if is ok to create each time function is called conn = new client(); or is better to delete previus conn from memory and then create new one?

Comment: Personnaly, I don't think you need to delete the object.

Comment: Thanks..i leave it like it is...now is working perfect..i try to click on button multiple times and no error anymore :)